# Merge [xcode-service] into [xcode-server]; remove [xcode-service] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Please retag all [xcode-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-service) questions as [xcode-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-server) and delete the [xcode-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-service) tag.

My edit of the [xcode-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode-server) tag summarizes the situation:

> Xcode Server is the name for the Xcode service in OS X Server. This is Apple's continuous integration product for iOS and OS X development. If you have questions specific to Bots in Xcode Server, use xcode-bots tag instead.

Supporting link from Apple: https://www.apple.com/support/osxserver/xcodeserver/